# c++ struct does not recognize the type of initializer list

Tags: c++, struct

```
 struct Advertising
 {
    int addCounter {0};
    int percentageClicked = 0;
    double clickValue = 0;
 };

Advertising addsJulio (10,20,0.11);
```

The first '10' is not recognized as an int ...

```
    Error: operations.cpp:54:38: error: no matching function for call to
 ‘Advertising::Advertising(int, int, double)’
```

IDE: VS Code
g++: 5.4
distr: Ubuntu

Comment: @PalLaden that's related but not quite same issue. OP misinterpreting  what he actually wrote, he rightfully wants an initializer-list here, but wrote different thing. C++ initialization syntax is a huge and mutable (along arrow of time , because standard changes) topic with multiple issues.

Answer (score 4):

That's not a initializer list,  one by definition would be surrounded by curly braces. You've called a constructor by using parenthesis. Both notations below may work.

```
 Advertising addsJulio1 {10,20,0.11}; 
 Advertising addsJulio2 ({10,20,0.11});
```

Also old-style, which works in C++98  for reasons that are different than post-C++11

```
Advertising addsJulio3 = {10,20,0.11};
```

With C++11 standard active GCC 5.4 would not consider that a proper initialization for `Advertising` unless inline initialization would be removed or appropriate constructor declared:

```
struct Advertising
 {
    int addCounter;
    int percentageClicked;
    double clickValue;
 };
```

or

```
struct Advertising
{
    int addCounter {0};
    int percentageClicked = 0;
    double clickValue = 0;
    
    Advertising() {}
    Advertising(int a ,int b, double c) :
          addCounter(a), percentageClicked(b), clickValue(c) {}
};
```

Comment: Obligatory [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis.  An hour long presentation on the initialization syntax pain point in C++.

Comment: @Eljay I saw it. I actually debated to add link to that one, at least it's also source of good laugh Nicolai's face in one of pages resembled mine when I learned some changes they did in 2014.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, thanks for the reply. I tried that and non of those seams to be invalid: the error: in C++98 ‘addsJulio’ must be initialized by constructor, not by ‘{...}’

Comment: @yo.alucino in your particular case you've made all members  incorrect by C+98 by inline-initializing them without being static and first member's initialization is not correct for that standard. The syntax of initialization via ={} is correct though as long as it doesn't contain conversions.  Avoiding inline initialization initialization, `Advertising` would become an aggregate. Technically this declaration you made have issue with interim standards as well because it wasn't default-constructible anymore.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie following your indication (I did not fully understand your answer) regarding the incorrect initialization I discovered that the problem is not in the call / creation of the structure, but rather in the definition which does not permit default values unless you have some sort of external contructor,

Comment: @yo.alucino That's correct for C++11. You're probably wa using an older standard which you failed to state, C++14 and C++17 would consider your original code correct after replacing parenthesis by curly braces,  Your question then should be tagged with C++11.